# Is it possible to combine interactive 3D content with the camera stream in Ionic?

Tags: cordova, three.js, ionic-framework, webrtc, crosswalk-runtime

I'm about to make an iOS/Android app that allows the user to interact with 3D content that overlays the live-stream coming from the device's camera. It's kind of AR-lite I guess as it doesn't need to 'see' the scene or recognise any objects within it. I like Ionic and ideally I would use it for this but I have no idea whether it is capable or not.

Here's the exact functionality required...

- User turns on their camera stream and points their device at a wall
- They see a 3D object overlaying the camera feed
- They can drag/pinch the object to move/scale/rotate it so that it looks right in the scene
- They can also use interface buttons to change properties of the object such as colour
- List item
- When they are happy they can click a 'save' button which saves the composited image to their device

I'm aware of Three JS and from it's demo pages it looks like it would be able to deliver the 3D rendering part of this project. Also doing a quick Google I have found that WebRTC will give me a camera stream, and that Crosswalk will implement this for me on all the devices I need.

So I was wondering whether anyone has experience with this and can answer a few questions for me which might save me a whole lot of time if it turns out it's not possible. The questions are...

1. Is it possible to overlay the interactive ThreeJS object over the WebRTC/Crosswalk camera stream in Ioinc?
2. Is it possible to get the composited image of these two and save it to the device?
3. If the answer to the above two is yes and there is a solution, how stable is it and how much device/browser support does it have?

Comment: You don't need WebRTC to show the camera feed on your screen. Saving the composite is a little bit more tricky: usual screen grabbing techniques will show black holes for camera and OpenGL, at least on Android. You must implement your own image saving, which will take care of overlaying the 3D object over the current frame.

Comment: Thanks Alex, so if I get the camera feed through anyway without WebRTC can I overlay the 3D content over that stream?

Comment: Sure you can; use `<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">` for camera, and transparent background for Three JS.

Comment: great, thanks Alex I'll give that a go